# how to join columns in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

login(id, name, role,user_id)
teacher(teacher_id)

I need to check role is 2.

```
$this->db->select('*');     
$this->db->from('teacher');     
$this->db->where('teacher_branch_id',$this->session->userdata('branch_id'));
$this->db->join('login','teacher.teacher_id = login.login_user_id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: What you want to find...............

Comment: you already joined ?? so where is problem ?

Comment: login.role = 2 in above query

Comment: suggest that you filter/check this value first and then pass to your query if valid: $this->session->userdata('branch_id')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a where condition like this: `$this->db->where('login.role', 2);`

```
$this->db->select('*');     
$this->db->from('teacher');     
$this->db->join('login', 'teacher.teacher_id = login.login_user_id');
$this->db->where('teacher_branch_id', $this->session->userdata('branch_id'));
$this->db->where('login.role', 2);

$query = $this->db->get();
```